# python json to csv converting script?

Tags: python

Let me start by stating that I am new to python. I wrote a script that will convert a .json file to csv format. I managed to write a script to do the job, however I don't think that my script will work if the format of the json file was to change. My script assumes that the json file will be in the same format at all times.

```
<json file example>
 {
"Order":
    {
        "order_id":"8251662",
        "order_date":"2012-08-20 13:17:37",
        "order_date_shipped":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "order_status":"fraudreview",
        "order_ship_firstname":"pam",
        "order_ship_lastname":"Gregorio",
        "order_ship_address1":"1533 E. Dexter St",
        "order_ship_address2":"",
        "order_ship_city":"Covina",
        "order_ship_state":"CA",
        "order_ship_zip":"91746",
        "order_ship_country":"US United States",
        "order_ship_phone":"6268936923",
        "order_ship_email":"pgregorio@brighton.com",
        "order_bill_firstname":"pam",
        "order_bill_lastname":"Gregorio",
        "order_bill_address1":"1533 E. Dexter St",
        "order_bill_address2":"",
        "order_bill_city":"Covina",
        "order_bill_state":"CA",
        "order_bill_zip":"91746",
        "order_bill_country":"US United States",
        "order_bill_phone":"6268936923",
        "order_bill_email":"pgregorio@brighton.com",
        "order_gift_message":"",
        "order_giftwrap":"0",
        "order_gift_charge":"0",
        "order_shipping":"Standard (Within 5-10 Business Days)",
        "order_tax_charge":"62.83",
        "order_tax_shipping":"0",
        "order_tax_rate":"0.0875",
        "order_shipping_charge":"7.5",
        "order_total":"788.33",
        "order_item_count":"12",
        "order_tracking":"",
        "order_carrier":"1"
    },

"Items":
    [
    {
        "item_id":"25379",
        "item_date_shipped":"",
        "item_code":"17345-J3553-J35532",
        "item_quantity":"2","item_taxable":"YES",
        "item_unit_price":"32","item_shipping":"0.67",
        "item_addcharge_price":"0",
        "item_description":" ABC Slide Bracelet: : Size: OS: Silver Sku: J35532",
        "item_quantity_returned":"0",
        "item_quantity_shipped":"0",
        "item_quantity_canceled":"0",
        "item_status":"pending",
        "item_product_id":"17345",
        "item_product_kit_id":"0",
        "item_product_sku":"J35532",
        "item_product_barcode":"881934310775",
        "item_tracking":"",
        "item_carrier":"0",
        "item_source_orderid":""
    },
    {
        "item_id":"25382",
        "item_date_shipped":"",
        "item_code":"17608-J3809-J3809C",
        "item_quantity":"1",
        "item_taxable":"YES",
        "item_unit_price":"22",
        "item_shipping":"0.23",
        "item_addcharge_price":"0",
        "item_description":" \"ABC Starter Bracelet 7 1\/4\"\"\": : Size: OS: Silver Sku: J3809C",
        "item_quantity_returned":"0",
        "item_quantity_shipped":"0",
        "item_quantity_canceled":"0",
        "item_status":"pending",
        "item_product_id":"17608",
        "item_product_kit_id":"0",
        "item_product_sku":"J3809C",
        "item_product_barcode":"881934594175",
        "item_tracking":"",
        "item_carrier":"0",
        "item_source_orderid":""
    },
    {
        "item_id":"25385",
        "item_date_shipped":"",
        "item_code":"17687-J9200-J92000",
        "item_quantity":"2",
        "item_taxable":"YES",
        "item_unit_price":"12",
        "item_shipping":"0.25",
        "item_addcharge_price":"0",
        "item_description":" ABC Cathedral Bead: : Size: OS: Silver Sku: J92000",
        "item_quantity_returned":"0",
        "item_quantity_shipped":"0",
        "item_quantity_canceled":"0",
        "item_status":"pending",
        "item_product_id":"17687",
        "item_product_kit_id":"0",
        "item_product_sku":"J92000",
        "item_product_barcode":"881934602832",
        "item_tracking":"",
        "item_carrier":"0",
        "item_source_orderid":""
    },
    {
        "item_id":"25388",
        "item_date_shipped":"",
        "item_code":"17766-J9240-J92402",
        "item_quantity":"2",
        "item_taxable":"YES",
        "item_unit_price":"22",
        "item_shipping":"0.46",
        "item_addcharge_price":"0",
        "item_description":" ABC Ice Diva Bead: : Size: OS: Silver Sku: J92402",
        "item_quantity_returned":"0",
        "item_quantity_shipped":"0",
        "item_quantity_canceled":"0",
        "item_status":"pending",
        "item_product_id":"17766",
        "item_product_kit_id":"0",
        "item_product_sku":"J92402",
        "item_product_barcode":"881934655838",
        "item_tracking":"",
        "item_carrier":"0",
        "item_source_orderid":""
    },
    ],

"FraudReasons":
    [
    {
        "order_id":"11957",
        "fraud_reason":"order total exceeds max amount"
    },
    {
        "order_id":"11957",
        "fraud_reason":"order exceeds max item count"
    }
]
}
```

My script currently works fine with this json file but It wont work if there is only one item or one fraudreason. Here is the code to my script.

```
<script code>
#!/usr/bin/python
import simplejson as json
import optparse
import pycurl
import sys
import csv

json_data = open(file)
data = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

csv_file = '/tmp/' + str(options.orderId) + '.csv'
orders = data['Order']
items = data['Items']
frauds = data['FraudReasons']

o = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'), lineterminator=',')

o.writerow([orders['order_id'],orders['order_date'],orders['order_date_shipped'],orders['order_status'],orders['order_ship_firstname'],orders['order_ship_lastname'],orders['order_ship_address1'],orders['order_ship_address2'],orders['order_ship_city'],orders['order_ship_state'],orders['order_ship_zip'],orders['order_ship_country'],orders['order_ship_phone'],orders['order_ship_email'],orders['order_bill_firstname'],orders['order_bill_lastname'],orders['order_bill_address1'],orders['order_bill_address2'],orders['order_bill_city'],orders['order_bill_state'],orders['order_bill_zip'],orders['order_bill_country'],orders['order_bill_phone'],orders['order_bill_email'],orders['order_gift_message'],orders['order_giftwrap'],orders['order_gift_charge'],orders['order_shipping'],orders['order_tax_charge'],orders['order_tax_shipping'],orders['order_tax_rate'],orders['order_shipping_charge'],orders['order_total'],orders['order_item_count'],orders['order_tracking'],orders['order_carrier']])

for item in items:
    o.writerow([item['item_id'],item['item_date_shipped'],item['item_code'],item['item_quantity'],item['item_taxable'],item['item_unit_price'],item['item_shipping'],item['item_addcharge_price'],item['item_description'],item['item_quantity_returned'],item['item_quantity_shipped'],item['item_quantity_canceled'],item['item_status'],item['item_product_id'],item['item_product_kit_id'],item['item_product_sku'],item['item_product_barcode'],item['item_tracking'],item['item_carrier'],item['item_source_orderid']])

for fraud in frauds:
    o.writerow([fraud['fraud_reason']],)
```

I also have not been able to figure out how not to use the labels I hope someone can help me with this

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [csv.DictWriter](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=dictwriter#csv.DictWriter):

```
    # It's considered best to stash the main logic of your script
    # in a main() function like this.
    def main(filename, options):
        with open(filename) as fi:
            data = json.load(fi)

        csv_file = '/tmp/' + str(options.orderId) + '.csv'
        order = data['Order']
        items = data['Items']
        frauds = data['FraudReasons']

        # Here's one way to keep this maintainable if the JSON
        # format changes, and you don't care too much about the
        # order of the fields...
        orders_fields = sorted(orders.keys())
        item_fields = sorted(items[0].keys()) if items else ()
        fraud_fields = sorted(fraud[0].keys()) if fraud else ()

        csv_options = dict(lineterminator=',')

        with open(csv_file, 'w') as fo:
            o = csv.DictWriter(fo, order_fields, **csv_options)
            o.writeheader()
            o.writerow(orders)

            fo.write('\n')  # Optional, if you want to keep them separated.
            o = csv.DictWriter(fo, item_fields, **csv_options)
            o.writeheader()
            o.writerows(items)

            fo.write('\n')  # Optional, if you want to keep them separated.
            o = csv.DictWriter(fo, fraud_fields, **csv_options)
            o.writeheader()
            o.writerows(frauds)

    # If this script is run from the command line, just run
    # main(). Here's the place to use `optparse`.
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(...) # You'll need to fill in the main() arguments...
```

If you need to specify the order of fields, assign them to a tuple like this:

```
orders_fields = (
    'order_id',
    'order_date',
    'order_date_shipped',
    # ... etc.
    )
```

Comment: David - Thank you for your post. It is helping me a lot. However what if I wanted to keep the order of the fields in the same order they show up in the json file?

Comment: One other question I am not familiar with this type of syntax (main) and all that. can you tell me how I would run it from the command line? I am sorry for such simple questions (dumb) I am new to python I am more familiar with Perl but I want to learn how to code in python too.

Comment: If run directly from the command line, the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block will execute. The main benefit of this setup is that you can later use the module as a library from another script. Here's an article on the matter: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm

Comment: If you need to specify the order of your fields, then replace `sorted(orders.keys())` and the like with a tuple of field name strings in the order you want them. I mainly did it this way so the answer would be shorter. :)

Comment: David,I forgot to mention that in my production server I have python 2.4 Your script is not working on that server.

Comment: I worked through it and got it to work on my production version. so if I want to specify the order then I have to set them up in a similar fashion as in my original script?

Comment: Oh yeah, I think the `with` keyword was introduced in 2.5, and the inline `... if ... else` is probably post-2.4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the json-generated object (`data`) for the names of the fields. To retain the input order, tell json to use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of plain `dict` (requires python 2.7):

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict as ordereddict

data = json.loads(open('mydata.json', object_pairs_hook=ordereddict)
orders = data['Order']
print orders.keys()  # Will print the keys in the order they were read
```

You can then use `orders.keys()` instead of your hard-coded list, either with `writerow` or (simpler) with `csv.DictWriter`.

Note that this uses the default `json`, not `simplejson`, and requires python 2.7 for the `ordered_pairs_hook` argument and the `OrderedDict` type.

**Edit:** Yeah, I see from the comments that you're stuck with 2.4. You can download an `ordereddict` from PyPi, and you can extend the [`JSONDecoder`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) class and pass it with the `cls` argument (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load)), instead of `object_pairs_hook`, but that's uglier and more work...

Comment: Thanks alexis, I got the script to work using the above suggestions. I wish I could upgrade to 2.7 so I can take advantage of some of these cool things. Do you know if I can install 2.7 along side my version?

Comment: I believe you can, but you'll have to figure out the how.

Comment: "I wish I could upgrade to 2.7" is like I was once on a RHEL without access to internet. My solution was using a python 2.7+ from http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads for my platform, install it somewhere and and run the python interpreter from there (you may want to put the installation path first in your PATH env var)